# How to configure Jacoco and Sonar in Maven build tool?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

I need to setup the code coverage in SonarQube using Jacoco. For this, I need to use the Maven build tool for building purpose.

I would need the code settings for this configuration. Please help me in this regard. SonarQube is running on Remote server.

Please help me how to setup the above configuration for one of my projects. I need to check the code coverage % in SonarQube (HTML) for my project X.

Thanks,
Gopi

Answer (score 3):

- Open Google
- Type `jacoco sonarqube`
- Open first result and [read documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin) (or look at the [sample project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut/ut-maven-jacoco))

Comment: Hi, I had configured Jacoco + Sonar in Maven.